# A recurring problem for me

Tags: wordplay, cipher

Tgus oyzzke was cibstrycted vt a wribg okacenebt if gabds.

What does the above phrase mean and what caused it to be like it is?

Comment: Consider this [meta post on ciphers/code puzzles](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original text:

> This puzzle was constructed by a wrong placement of hands

You can see that several letters of the text have been replaced by a letter one left on a QWERTY keyboard. So moving your right hand one position left on all fingers and then typing the intended message as you normally would results in the message given in the puzzle

Comment: Dammit, beat me to this, I was writing last word :D

Comment: Same, was just about to type it out haha +1

Comment: Correct. 7 minutes seems like a good time for a simple puzzle. Will accept it when I can.

Comment: I figured it was a right race, surprised I made it. Also good link to the meta post @GordonAllocman

Comment: I'm a programmer and it's common (more than it should be) to start typing and then see that the words are all weird. Usually my left hand knows the correct placement, but the right hand sometimes thinks that the letters are closer than they should

Comment: oyvkuc statuc viud naub(Strubg[] args)

Comment: @NeedAName So it's not just me?